# I Need Help Converting C# “(byte)value” to Python

Tags: python, c#, arrays, byte

```
var orderId=188253;
var partnerId=251;

byte[] idBytes = new byte[8] { (byte)partnerId, (byte)(partnerId >> 8), (byte)(partnerId >> 16), (byte)(partnerId >> 24), (byte)orderId, (byte)(orderId >> 8), (byte)(orderId >> 16), (byte)(orderId >> 24)};
```

in C# i'm getting the value of `((byte)orderId) = 93`,

but in python I'm getting `(orderId.to_bytes) = 188253`

and if I tried in python `((bytes)orderId)`

I'm getting: `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0`

I need to get the same value

Comment: `but in python I'm getting (orderId.to_bytes) = 188253` Really? That's clearly wrong.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, and i donno why, do you have any idea hwa to solve it?

Comment: Is it just how you are displaying the result? Are you doing `print(orderId.to_bytes(8, 'big'))` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson no i want to return idBytes but this code returns a different result in python than in C# and want the result to be the same this is happening because the result of (byte)orderId not returning the same result for (orderId.to_bytes) in python